# Reactjs App request.get

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, cors, package.json

I have a react js app which does a simple http get. It does not use webpack and  use package.json

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8181/api/v1/status',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  }
}

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
    console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

This code is getting failed and I am getting the following error

> localhost/:1 Failed to load http://localhost:8181/api/v1/status: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The server which I am trying to access is running python and I am already appending  necessary header to make the request.
I am quite new to reactjs

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's breakdown the error message. The first part:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Means your Python server did not set an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You should make sure your python server sets this header in the response. If that didn't work, continue:

> The response had HTTP status code 405.

HTTP Status Code 405 means method not allowed. Your python server may also need to set the header: `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: <method>, <method>`. So in  include each one you want to allow, such as `GET, POST, OPTIONS`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods